# using forfiles to skip certain files and archive them

Tags: cmd, archive

I have a task where I need to archive some text files from a location to another also I need to skip certain files.

So far I have been able to archive all txt files from one path to another using `FORFILES` in CMD, but unable to skip certain files:

```
forfiles /p "path" /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c copy @file destination"
```

Comment: What is the criteria of the files that you want to skip?

Comment: by certain i mean based on extension and file not modified in last 30 days